# My motherboard doesn't support AHCI, is IDE mode + SATA 2 much slower for new SSD/HDD/SSHD?

Tags: sata, sshd, ssd

My motherboard is Intel DG41TY and it does not support AHCI. How much would IDE mode + SATA 2 be slower comparing to ideal case AHCI+SATA 3? If it is much slower for SSD case, then would it be a good idea for me to get SSHD since it is little bit more expensive than HDD, but still can give me a good speed improvement even though not as good as SSD?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question when I got my Vertex 2 SATA II and here is what I got from some tests on crystal diskmark (My mobo could be configured with AHCI and I wanted to see the dif. in each mode):

This was the SSD on a SATA II port with ide.

[image: before AHCI]

Same drive same port, bios changed to ACHI:

[image: after ACHI]

I got a PCIe to SATA III card(As I got a good deal on two more Kingston Hyper X SATA III SSDs) and hooked the same drive to that card with AHCI enabled for this result:

[image: SATA 3]

For the sake of comparison to a platter drive with IDE and AHCI mode see this:
[image: segate]

I do not think you will see much difference from a SSD to a SSHD in ide mode. The SSD and hybrid drive will perform much better than a platter drive in the same ide mode.

Comment: thx for answer with details. Dont understand why hdd with ahci has slower 4k qd=32 while ncq should be on comparing to ide, but number is small anyway.

Comment: Did you disable read/write caching when doing these tests?  Otherwise you are measuring the completely wrong thing.

Comment: @BlueRaja - nope. I left everything as it was and ran the tests. I wanted to see the difference AHCI made.

Comment: If you do not disable read/write caching, you are not testing AHCI, you're testing your OS's proficiency at caching.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you connect your SSD to a SATA2 port, it will still be bottle necked by the speed of the sata port. It will be a noticeable difference from a HDD, but you'll only be running at about half of your SSD's potential (Depending on your SSD).

Here's some more information on different speeds while connected to different SATA ports: http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i,-sata-ii-and-sata-iii